# Call a method after jQuery POST

Tags: jquery

When I use .click event I can call the method.
**WORKING**

```
$("#signin").live('click',function(){
    jsTouch.loadPage('pages/tabs.html', { transition: 'pop-in' });
});
```

When I use the jQuery.post it fails to load the method.
**FAILED**

```
$("#signin").live('click',function(){       
$.post("http://localhost/myAPI/index.php/api/requestlogin", { username: "admin", password: "test" },
function(data) {
        if(data.response == 'success')
            {                   
            jsTouch.loadPage('pages/tabs.html', { transition: 'pop-in' });
                     }else{
                        alert(data.response);               
                          }
});
});
```

**CONSOLE ERROR**
TypeError: Cannot call method 'loadPage' of undefined

Here is the jstouch library.
https://github.com/vitmalina/Web-2.0-Touch/blob/master/includes/jsTouch.js

Comment: What do you mean by "fails to load the method"? You need to tell us exactly what is happening, what you're seeing, what error messages you're getting in the console, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `.live()` is depreciated. Use `.on()` instead: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Okay so I've re-written your code with the AJAX function that I use. $.POST is, yes, short-hand for $.ajax, but give this a try anyway :)

---

```
$("body").on('click', '#signin', function(){       
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/myAPI/index.php/api/requestlogin",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {username: "admin", password: "test"},
        success: function(response) 
        {           
            jsTouch.loadPage('pages/tabs.html', { transition: 'pop-in' });
        },
        error: function(response)
        {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Once we know that you're using code that should definitely be working, and still nothing happens, you need to check the following, in this order:

- That the click is indeed registering, so put an alert just after the click.
- That the POST is indeed going through, so put an alert in the success function.
- If still nothing happens, it's your `jsTouch.loadPage()` that's not working.

Comment: This is the console log.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'loadPage' of null jsTouch.js:31
jsTouch.loadPage jsTouch.js:31
$.ajax.success (program):12
b jquery.js:124
x.onreadystatechange

Comment: Then the issue is with your `jsTouch.loadPage()` if it's getting that far. We have no idea what this function does, so you'll need to post more information.

Comment: All I can see is that you need to make sure that 'pages/tabs.html' exists where it should do for `jsTouch.loadPage()` to work correctly.

Comment: Here's the jstouch library.
https://github.com/vitmalina/Web-2.0-Touch/blob/master/includes/jsTouch.js

Comment: Are you sure you included the jsTouch.js script file in the page?

Comment: Yes I included all the required files.If I use onclick="jsTouch.loadPage('pages/tabs.html', { transition: 'pop-in' });"
this works but I want to validate user first from the server so i use jquery.post.